# How to open alertDialog on click of Button in Next Activity from First Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have Activity A and Activity B with one button Each. I would like to Open an Alert Dialog in Activity B when user press Button in A and Similarly in From Activity B when user press Button, Again alert Dialog should appear in Activity A.

I could either use **Shared prefrences.**.. and could override the onStart method to check the value and show alert dialog

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
super.onStart();
//Alert Dialog here
}
```

but if there is any other way..I can implement this ?

Note:
User can also navigate from menu between Activity A and B so I don't want to show any alert dialog when they use menu to navigate between two activites. But only when they press the Button.

Comment: When Activity B is not visible, how can you show alert dialog there ?

Comment: @VivekMishra On click the activity A will finish and B will start but alert dialog should appear B activity if user has pressed Button from A.

Comment: then using shared preference or passing via intent is a good option

Comment: No need to use sharedpreference for this. When you start activity B, just pass a boolean (via bundle) which will determine if 'something' needs to be done (open alertdialog in this case) when Activity B starts.

Comment: I was searching on internet..and then I followed some topics on result code or request code..Does they only use for starting new activity and get the result back to same activity or instead set result code to value on Onclick listener and start next activity  and based on value show alert dialog in Next activity..is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity A :

```
Intent k = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
k.putExtra("shouldStartAlertDialog", true);
startActivity(k);
```

Then in Activity B, in OnCreate method :

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("shouldStartAlertDialog", false)){
   //Show alertdialog
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Azhar....This can also be an good aprroach..I was thinking why should I use Sharedprefrence if I  don't want to save any value and just start an Dialog box....This is really helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. You are right, sharedpreference is used for storing infos which you want to retain for long term and which can be accessed anywhere in the App like User settings. For data that need to be shared while moving between activities only, you should use the above approach.

Comment: If the answer worked, please mark it as solution :)

Comment: There is one issue with this answer. Since in question it is said that activity can be opened from  menu too , so you either put false for the flag or check whether intent has that key or not or else it will crash

Comment: @VivekMishra : the default value is false for the getBooleanExtra. If nothing is sent from Activity A, the method getIntent().getBooleanExtra("shouldStartAlertDialog", false) will return false. It won't crash.

Comment: I am not saying about default value case, I am saying about the case when you don't send the key

Answer (score 1):

You can set bundle in intent extras

```
private void startActivity(boolean showDialog,Class activity){
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("show_dialog",showDialog);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, activity);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Now call start activity like this

```
startActivity(true,ActivityB.class)
```

in you ActivityB's onCreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean showDialog = extras.getBoolean("show_dialog",false);
if(showDialog)  // code to show dialog
```